# How do I create a query that would give me the latest two record for each user

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which i am storing the attendance of each user. I have many users, I want to return each users **last two record**. Recently updated record

Comment: Give examples so we can at least see what columns you have available

Comment: Using this query i am getting last 1 record, but i want to get two records of each employee 
SELECT * 
 FROM tblAttData 
 WHERE att_ID IN 
(SELECT MAX(att_ID)
 FROM 
  tblAttData 
 GROUP BY
  att_EmpId)

Comment: Examples of the data, with all the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
  sorted_att AS
(
  SELECT
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY att_empID
                           ORDER BY att_ID DESC
                      )
                        AS att_emp_sequence_id
  FROM
    tblAttData
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted_att
WHERE
  att_emp_sequence_id <= 2
```